# Spark forEach vs Map functions

Tags: apache-spark, dictionary, foreach

I was going to through a review and it was stated:

forEach forces all of the data to be sent to a single process (the Driver) 
which will cause issues (such as OutOfMemory issues) at scale.  Instead the 
map() function serves the same purpose and distributes processing across 
different Worker nodes in the cluster.

Is it correct, I could not find any document which says forEach is not distributed while map is distributed!!!

Answer (score 2):

I believe you talking about applying these functions on RDD or Dataset.
Nothing comes to driver in either case. All code is executed in executor. foreach is an action that returns nothing where as map() acts as transformer from one value to other.

def foreach(f: (T) ⇒ Unit): Unit
Applies a function f to all elements of this RDD.

foreach(func)   Run a function func on each element of the dataset. This is usually done for side effects such as updating an Accumulator or interacting with external storage systems. 
Note: modifying variables other than Accumulators outside of the foreach() may result in undefined behavior. See Understanding closures for more details.

def map[U](f: (T) ⇒ U)(implicit arg0: ClassTag[U]): RDD[U]
Return a new RDD by applying a function to all elements of this RDD.